# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index must be within the bounds of the List

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

So i am using kendo UI in my MVC project and i am using grid to display the data.But i am keep getting this error.

My Controller:

```
[ActionName("session-confirm")]
public ActionResult SessionConfirm()
{

    AddSessionViewModel objviewmodel = new AddSessionViewModel();
    List<ErrorListViewModel> objError = new List<ErrorListViewModel>();

var ErrorList = TempData["ErrorArry"] as List<String>;
       //int i = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < ErrorList.Count; i = i + 5)
    {

        objError.Add(new ErrorListViewModel
        {

            Child = ErrorList[i],
            Error1 = ErrorList[i+1],
            Error2 = ErrorList[i+2],
            Error3 = ErrorList[i+3],
            Error4 = ErrorList[i+4]
        });

    }
   objviewmodel.ErrorArry = objError;
    return View(objviewmodel);
```

**[Update]**
Even i tired replacing my controller with this:

```
string sid = "6";
            var ResultinComplete = db.sp_get_MandateInfo(sid).ToList();

            foreach (var list in ResultinComplete)
            {
                objError.Add(new ErrorListViewModel
                 {

                    Child = list.GroupSize,
                    Error1 = list.Language,
                    Error2 = list.Location,
                    Error3 = list.Frequency

                });
            }
```

My View is:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.ErrorArry)
               .Name("Grid")
               .Columns(Columns => 
                   {
                       Columns.Bound(m => m.Child).Width(200).Title("Child");

                       Columns.Bound(m => m.Error1).Width(200).Title("Group Size")
                            .Template(@<text> 
                       @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Error1))
                       {
                                           <span >@TempData["Group"]</span>
                       }
                       else
                       {
                                            <span style="color:Red;">@TempData["Group"]</span>
                       } 
                                           </text>);
                       Columns.Bound(m => m.Error2).Width(200).Title("Duration")
                           .Template(@<text> 
                       @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Error2))
                       {
                                           <span >@TempData["Duration"]</span>
                       }
                       else
                       {
                                            <span style="color:Red;">@TempData["Duration"]</span>
                       } 
                                           </text>);
                       Columns.Bound(m => m.Error3).Width(200).Title("Language")
                            .Template(@<text> 
                       @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Error3))
                       {
                                           <span >@TempData["Language"]</span>
                       }
                       else
                       {
                                            <span style="color:Red;">@TempData["Language"]</span>
                       } 
                                           </text>);

                   })
                   .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)
            .PageSizes(true)
            .ButtonCount(5))


            .Sortable()
            )
```

I check the Kendo UI reference and it was fine, In my code i have TempDate["ErrorArry"] which is nx5 array dumped into TempData.

I saw few solutions regarding web.config setting but didnt worked for me.
i added

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

but was getting web.config error on page.I guess it because i have this line already in my web.config file

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>

        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity,oldVersion=1.0.0.0-4.0.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />

      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
```

Anyone have any idea whats the issue?

Comment: What happen if ErrorList.Count = 2 ? I mean, are you sure that the ErrorList contains always errors in multiple of five as required by your loop?

Comment: So i just updated my question. Yes it will always be in multiple of 5.the one i just debuged had 10 values in TempData and ErrorList.Count was 2 for that.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. If ErrorList.Count is 2 then you cannot access ErrorList[i + 2] this will give the error in your question

Comment: My bad @Steve its late here(2 Am), so my ErrorList have 10 values(which will be always in multiple of 5).When i debug its going through fine my controller but i am getting this error when my code reaches my view file